# asp.net y crystal reports no muestra crystalreportviewer

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports, reportviewer

Estoy empezando con asp.net y crystal reports estoy haciendo algo simple para empezar en el .aspx agrego un crystalreportviewer tengo un data set y un reporte en crystal lleno el dataset con este codigo, estoy seguro que el dataset se llena y que tiene informacion sin embargo no muestra el control pareciera que esta invisible el control, les agradecería cualquier apoyo o guía.

He investigado parece ser problema del control pero no he logrado solucionarlo.

```
    CrystalReportViewer1.Visible = True

    dsApp = New dsReportes
    Dim ReportDocument As ReportDocument = New ReportDocument()
    ReportDocument.Load(Server.MapPath("~\Reportes\lclientes.rpt"))
    CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = ReportDocument

    dsApp = Man.clientessp()
    ReportDocument.SetDataSource(dsApp)

    CrystalReportViewer1.DataBind()
```

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a [es.so]. Nótese que esta pregunta tiene problemas de formato. Dale a [edit](/edit) para modificarla. También puede serte de interés realizar el [tour] y leer [ask].

Answer (score 0):

La respuesta si alguien se encuentra con el mismo problema esta en:

[Crystal Report doesnt display in ASP.net webpage which is build by using VS 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26753853/crystal-report-doesnt-display-in-asp-net-webpage-which-is-build-by-using-vs-2013)

Comment: pues edita esto por favor y coloca todo lo necesario aqui

Comment: pues responder con solo enlaces se considera de baja calidad, lee [answer]